# Is "at the middle" ever correct?

Tags: prepositions

A sentence from a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarface_(1983_film)) reads:

> **At the middle of the film**, Scorsese turned to Bauer and told him, "You guys are great – but be prepared, because they're going to hate it in Hollywood... because it's about them."

I thought it should be ***in** the middle of the film*. Several online posts also suggest that the preposition used with *the middle* should be **in** not **at**. Is it a mistake in the sentence at issue?

Comment: **at** is fine there. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22at+the+middle+of+the+movie%22&oq=%22at+the+middle+of+the+movie%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.6285j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In* the middle is [much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=*%20the%20middle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3):

[image]

"*At* the middle" might be fine, especially if you are making a direct comparison to something that happens *at* the end, or *at* the beginning of the film.

Personally, I would have written "*in* the middle", as I think it sounds more natural.